# MySQL user defined function with nested query inside

Tags: mysql, user-defined-functions

I want to create a mysql function to get due date (90 work days from start_date) based on my local holiday calendar. The query in my PHP function is like this..

```
select max(col_date) as due_date from (select col_date from ref_calendar where holiday=0 and col_date>'".$start_date."' limit 90) as a
```

I want to make it as a mysql function so I can just query "duedate(start_date)" to get the due date.

I have tried but still failed.

```
CREATE FUNCTION duedate(st_date DATE)
DECLARE datedue DATE
BEGIN
SELECT MAX(col_date) INTO datedue from (select col_date from ref_calendar where holiday=0 and col_date>st_date limit 90);
RETURN datedue;
END
```

Comment: How did you fail?

Comment: SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE datedue DATE BEGIN SELECT MAX(col_date) INTO datedue from (select col_' at line 2

Comment: Problem resolved.

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION duedate (st_date DATE) 
RETURNS DATE 
RETURN
  (select max(a.col_date) FROM (select col_date from ref_calendar where holiday=0 and col_date>st_date limit 90) as a);

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved. This is my final code after read MariaDB knowledge base.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION duedate (st_date DATE) 
RETURNS DATE 
RETURN (select max(a.col_date) FROM (select col_date from ref_calendar where holiday=0 and col_date>st_date limit 90) as a);
```

Thank you! :)